# This string in various log from linux "ÿôÿý"

Tags: linux, string, character, logging

Anyone knows why the "ÿôÿý" string appears in various logs on Linux? I cannot figure it out.  It does not appear every time, but when it does it makes the log (oracle backup log for example) difficult to read. 
Any help/hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: bad termtype? strange locale? unicode corruption?  That is not an intentional "linux log string" that I've seen

Comment: what are the hex values for those characters, that information would be more useful than their appearance in one particular encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a telnet command sequence that was intended to be interpreted as a command by some communications software, but for some reason got passed through as ordinary characters rather than being interpreted as a telnet command.

All telnet commands start with the byte 0xff followed by another byte identifying the command.  0xff will display as ÿ in ISO Latin-1.  0xff 0xf4 (ÿô) is a telnet Interrupt Process command, which should send a SIGINT signal to the process (like ^C).  0xff 0xfd (ÿý) is the beginning of a telnet DO command, used to negotiate turning on some telnet option; it should be followed by another byte identifying the specific option (although it may be a non-printing control character).

Comment: Thank you very much, mark4o. This helps a lot, now I know where to start! Thanks again!